# Query regarding @Cacheable in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a Student entity and I am having three different ways to retrieve a Student record using the student_id, student_phone and student_email. The student controller and data retrieval methods are as follows.

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/get")
    public ResponseEntity<?> get(@RequestParam(required = false, name = "phone") String phoneNumber,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String email, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer id) {
        try {
            ReadStudentRequestModel res = null;
            if (phoneNumber != null)
                res = studentCRUDService.readStudentUsingPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            else if (email != null)
                res = studentCRUDService.readStudentUsingEmail(email);
            else if (id != null)
                res = studentCRUDService.readStudentUsingId(id);
            else throw new BadRequestException("Unable to find Student: wrong parameters provided.");

            Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            map.put("status", 1);
            map.put("message", "Success");
            map.put("data", res);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(BadRequestException e){
            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            map.put("status", 0);
            map.put("message", "Failed");
            map.put("error", e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            map.put("status", 0);
            map.put("message", "Failed");
            map.put("error", e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

**Data retrieval methods**

```
@Service
public class StudentCRUDService{
 @Cacheable(value="LibraryManagement_Student", key="#phoneNumber")
    public ReadStudentRequestModel readStudentUsingPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) throws Exception {
        Student s = repo.getByPhone(phoneNumber);

        return ReadStudentRequestModel.builder()
                .age(s.getAge())
                .name(s.getName())
                .email(s.getEmail())
                .country(s.getCountry())
                .phoneNumber(s.getPhoneNumber())
                .id(s.getId())
                .card(s.getCard())
                .createdOn(s.getCreatedOn())
                .updatedOn(s.getUpdatedOn())
                .build();

    }

    @Cacheable(value="LibraryManagement_Student", key="#email")
    public ReadStudentRequestModel readStudentUsingEmail(String email) throws Exception {

        Student s = repo.getByEmail(email);

        return ReadStudentRequestModel.builder()
                .age(s.getAge())
                .name(s.getName())
                .email(s.getEmail())
                .country(s.getCountry())
                .phoneNumber(s.getPhoneNumber())
                .id(s.getId())
                .card(s.getCard())
                .createdOn(s.getCreatedOn())
                .updatedOn(s.getUpdatedOn())
                .build();
    }

    @Cacheable(value="LibraryManagement_Student", key="#id")
    public ReadStudentRequestModel readStudentUsingId(Integer id) throws Exception {
        Optional<Student> response = repo.findById(id);

        if(response.isEmpty())throw new Error("Student does not exist.");

        Student s = response.get();

        return ReadStudentRequestModel.builder()
                .age(s.getAge())
                .name(s.getName())
                .email(s.getEmail())
                .country(s.getCountry())
                .phoneNumber(s.getPhoneNumber())
                .id(s.getId())
                .card(s.getCard())
                .createdOn(s.getCreatedOn())
                .updatedOn(s.getUpdatedOn())
                .build();

    }
}
```

Now the problem is with key attribute in @Cacheable annotations.
In the above methods you can see in the key attribute I have to give different keys in different cases that is creating inconsistency. For example,
Suppose I have fetched same student object using these different objects. Hence three records will be generated for same object in the db. Now if I try to delete that student using id, I will be unable to delete the other two objects from the cache.
Please suggest where am I wrong?

....................

Comment: The `cacheManager` could be an injected dependency, so that when the DB record is deleted (or updated), the `ReadStudentRequestModel` instances could be evicted from all of those caches.

Comment: @Cacheable is not designed to be used for OR condition rather it is cache for definitive key. 
You will need to evict all 3 keys before deleting the object from database, so this way you can keep the consistent behavior.

Comment: You aren't gaining much by caching this, at least not enough to warrant the trouble.  That database query will likely be just as fast as your cache lookup so before you spend time trying to solve this edge case, consider whether you even need it.